# Image is not showing up on frontend after fetching from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

**Hello i am working on my fyp and i am new to react js and node js i have successfully stored my image in mongoDB database when i upload the image the image is stored in a local storage in my case it is stored in a folder named "uploads" and the name of image is stored in database and when i try to fetch image by giving path of locally stored image + name stored in database it does not show any image rather it shows a broken image. the name of the image is stored in a variable name "profileImage" and it is retrieving from database properly. dont know what is the issue anyone here to guide me . Screenshot of output and code is attached for reference.**

**Code For Frontend and get api**

````
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios'


const About = () =>{
const history = useHistory();

const [id, setID] = useState('');
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
const [work, setWork] = useState('');
const [profileimage, setPimage] = useState('');


const CallAbtPageA=()=>{
  axios.get('/about')
  .then((res) => {
    setID(res.data.id);
    setName(res.data.name);
    setEmail(res.data.email);
    setPhone(res.data.phone);
    setWork(res.data.work);
    setPimage(res.data.photo);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    history.push('/login');
  });

}


useEffect(()=>{
  CallAbtPageA();
});

  return(
  <div>
    <form method="GET"  encType="multipart/form-data">
      <div> <h1 style={{display:'inline',color:'black'}}>ID:</h1>    <p style={{display:'inline',fontSize:"35px"}}>{name}</p> </div>
      <div> <h1 style={{display:'inline',color:'black'}}>Name:</h1>    <p style={{display:'inline',fontSize:"35px"}}>{name}</p> </div>
      <div> <h1 style={{display:'inline',color:'black'}}>EMAIL:</h1>    <p style={{display:'inline',fontSize:"35px"}}>{email}</p> </div>
      <div> <h1 style={{display:'inline',color:'black'}}>PHONE:</h1>    <p style={{display:'inline',fontSize:"35px"}}>{phone}</p> </div>
      <div> <h1 style={{display:'inline',color:'black'}}>WORK:</h1>    <p style={{display:'inline',fontSize:"35px"}}>{work}</p> </div>
    </form>
    <div> <h1 style={{display:'inline',color:'black'}}>PROFILE PIC:</h1> <img src = {`./uploads/${profileimage}`}  /> </div>
  </div>
)
 }

 export default About;``` 



[![Screenshot of output][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWtw4.png

[![Screenshot of Response is in below link][2]][2]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVPfi.png
````

Comment: I believe using ```useEffect``` like this will cause an infinite loop, put an empty array in the dependencies list 
aslo you need to explain if ```profileimage``` is absolute or relative link

Comment: profileimage is a variable in which i am fetching the name of image from database

Comment: can u then please me tell how can make it work

Comment: add a screenshot of the response, you will find it in the google chrome network tab

Comment: i have attached the screenshot of response kindly have a look at that and guide me how can i do it in correct way

Comment: where are you hosting your image ?

Comment: actually i am storing image in a local storage in my project directory whenever the user upload a picture the actual picture is stored in a folder named "uploads" in my project and the name of image is stored in mongoDB so when it comes to show image i just simply give the path of of upload folder and the name of image from database in source of image like <img src=`./uploads/${profileimage}` />

Answer (score 0):

what is your api backend? image is not found there because may be you are not serving your static image assets.

Comment: can you please elaborate it more?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your uploads folder is not acccessed publicly. So, to resolve this you have to serve the folder as static in Express.

Try this in nodejs:

app.use('/uploads',express.static('uploads'))

Comment: i have tried this but same results